# Microsoft Cognitive Speech SDK for UWP apps

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, .net-core

I am looking to incorporate the **Microsoft Cognitive Speech SDK** for C# into a UWP app. But after some research I could see that, the sdk works only on .NET framework and not on .net core (on which UWP is based on). So is there any workaround to make it work on .net core? Any ways to convert it like PCL or via .NET Standard?

Note: I am aware of REST API services, but it has a 15 sec restriction for speech recognition. But I am looking for a continuous recognition mode.

Also I tried out Windows 10 built-in speech recognition, but it isn't accurate enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a .NET Standard library, reference the SDK from there and then create a class that will act as a adapter to access the required functionality of the SDK from UWP. But there might be issues if the SDK uses some APIs which are not implemented in UWP.

To avoid the REST API limitation, you could [follow the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/api-reference-rest/websocketprotocol) to connect to the service via WebSockets. There seems to be no library that does this right now so you will have implement it yourself. UWP itself has [built-in support for WebSockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/websockets) so this should be possible to do.